# Timestamping BLE packets in android

Tags: android, adb, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to know the exact time stamp when an bluetooth low energy packet was received by the android phone. I am trying :

```
adb logcat -b events
```

I also tried radio. But it doesnt seem to print this data. Whats the lowest level where a timestamped bluetooth packet can be read by me? I want to know the processing time when it forwards it to the upper layer of android. Could someone please help me out?